# Linux Mint - Cinnamon - How to trigger a visual feedback from terminal

Tags: bash, linux-mint, x11, audio, cinnamon

During my work i run some bash scripts on linux terminal that takes 5 to 6 minutes to complete. I would like to append some command on that scripts, so that when it finish, it shows some visual feedback on the cinnamon window, like a blink or somethink like.

For now I use the espeak command to send me some sound, but it's not so good, since most of the time I don't work using earphones.

Comment: notify-send 'title' 'message' is perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make your screen "blink" by refreshing it.

```
for (( i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++ ))
do
  xrefresh -solid blue
  xrefresh -solid red
  xrefresh -solid green
  sleep 0.01
done
```

This should get your attention and get you in the mood for some epileptic dancing. Tune it up or down to your liking or just use part of your screen (`-geometry` option).

Comment: cannot make it work. tried: xrefresh -solid blue -geometry 200x200+0+0 && sleep 1

Comment: Try a few repetitions quickly after each other, it might be too fast.